# Task.Delay() cancellation not working on net7.0?

Tags: c#, .net

Would anyone know why `await Task.Delay(longTimeOut, cancellationToken);` does not end up with `TaskCanceledException` (when the token is signalled) and continue waiting when targeting `net7.0`?

On `net6.0` it throws as expected.

**EDIT:**

As stated below, the original question is misleading... Anyway between the `net6`/`net7` there is a difference in the process termination caused by `Console.CancelKeyPress`, where on `net6` there is some room for the task to report it's cancellation and throwing the exception, on `net7` the process seems to be killed faster and thus the code handling cancellation is not even executed.

Comment: Please edit your post with a minimal reproducible sample

Comment: Although I was firstly wondering, how is it possible you cannot imagine the basic boiler plate around the statement above, I then have realized your point... Will post in the answer.

Comment: Are you catching `TaskCanceledException ` or `OperationCanceledException` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine here; output:

```
TaskCanceledException
Took: 00:00:03.0577829
```

dotnet --info:

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23
 Commit:    0a5360315a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22000
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.0-rc.2.22472.3
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       550605cc93
```

test:

```cs
var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancel.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{
    // works identically if a large integer is passed
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), cancel.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("no fault");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name);
}
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Took: {watch.Elapsed}");
```

If you're seeing something different: please post an entire runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: The question is a bit misleading...

The main problem was the point where the `cancellationToken` got fired: `Console.CancelKeyPress`. Not sure why it works differently between `net6`/`net7` (which I incorrectly stated as the cause), but there is the `e.Cancel`, which is counterintuitive (at leas for me) and I left the default value of false, and probably the whole process went the wrong way.

When I added automatic cancellation, it works as expected (so it's clear it's not the `Task.Delay()`'s issue).

```
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10_000); // cancelling automatically

        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelling manually...");
            cts.Cancel();
            e.Cancel = true; // This is the issue, as default is false, meaning: "Terminate the process after return."
        };

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            await Task.Delay(20_000, cts.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Cancelled: {ex}.");
        }
    }
```

Meaning: on `net6` the task is cancelled even when the process is terminating. On `net7` it's not. At least in the debugger in Visual Studio (haven't tried plain executable).

Comment: Edit the *question* and add this code there. Otherwise it makes little sense and will confuse others - cancellation works

Comment: `e.Cancel = true;` means `cancel the event` in al BCL events that have such a property. For unhandled exception events the equivalent is `Handled`. This isn't new behavior, even the .NET Framework 1.1 docs explain this

Comment: I haven't said it's anything new. It's just subjectively counter intuitive.